# How do I handle editText Send event in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new to Kotlin and I'm stuck at a specific point.
I have this EditText in one of my UI Fragments:

```
            <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="start|top"
            android:imeOptions="actionSend"
            android:inputType="text" />
```

How do I now call a function by clicking on the send button on the keyboard. 
And could anyone please let me know where do I've to put that code.

Thank you very much!

Comment: you want to preform action on send button or send anything on done button on keyboard..?

Comment: send anything on done button on keyboard!

Answer (score 0):

This way to write in kotlin

```
editText3.setOnEditorActionListener { textView , actionId, event ->
        if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND){
            //doSomething()
            true
        } else {
            false
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried this. This is the error I get: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setOnEditorActionListener(android.widget.TextView$OnEditorActionListener)' on a null object reference

I put the code in the MainActivity. Is that the problem?